# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset on VPN

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, jakarta-mail, javax.imageio

I am trying to fetch mails from gmail and i am able to fetch the mails but whenever i connect to VPN i.e my office VPN  i am getting exception

Code:

```
MailSSLSocketFactory sf = new MailSSLSocketFactory();
        sf.setTrustAllHosts(true);

        properties.load(input);
        properties.put( "mail.imap.ssl.socketFactory", sf);

        session = Session.getInstance(properties);
        // connects to the message store
        store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(properties.getProperty("username"), properties.getProperty("password"));
        folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
```

Properties file:

```
mail.imap.host=imap.gmail.com
mail.imap.socketFactory.port=993
mail.imap.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback=false
mail.imap.ssl.enable=true
mail.imap.auth=true
mail.imap.port=993
username=example.gmail.com
password=**********
```

Is there anyother way to automate email receive functionality.
The end goal I am trying to achive is to test the  email sent by the Application is received by user or not and also validate the data it contains

Comment: Your office network might have some firewalls blocking outbound connection

Comment: yes, how can i solve this issue. does it have to do something with certificates?

Comment: I don't  think so. Check with your network admin, is the outbound ports blocked or what restrictions you have in place. BTW, What is the error you are facing?

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: I think its a firewall problem only.

Comment: ok can you suggest any other way to achieve this.

Comment: what would be the best way to receive emails

Comment: I am able to telnet the port 993

Comment: Get rid of all the [socket factory settings](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes).  Post the exact error message you're getting, along with the [debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  Disable your firewall for testing, and if that works learn how to configure your firewall to allow your test program to connect.